# Define APEX virtual directory in a mapped network drive

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to change the Oracle APEX virtual path directory /i/ in dads.conf to point to a specific folder or map drive in a network share folder for example:

```
Alias /i/ "t:/images/"
```

t: is a map drive in another storage server.

or:

```
  Alias /i/ "//10.10.10.1/images/"
```

I'm using OHS on Oracle APEX 5.1..00.09
What permissions do I have to set and what is the best practice serious to implement this.

Comment: It works when I tired to use a share folder in the same server Alias /i/ "//localhost/images/" , but I want it to be in different server

Answer (score 0):

It works when I tired to use a share folder in the same server Alias /i/ "//localhost/images/" , but I want it to be in different server